# Power Grid in depth explanation

Tags: transmission-line, power-engineering, power-electronics

I am looking for links, books, papers, documents or any other reference type that allows me to get a very in depth overview of the power transmission and distribution network (preferably of the UK). By that I mean physical characteristics of substations, feeders, transformer stations, their links, and so on.

I have searched all over the web and found parts here and there, but I can't find anything that links everything or covers the entire grid. Neither can I find very in depth explanations on the subject matter (e.g. energy losses, frequency control, Reactive-/Active- Power issues, etc.).

Thanks already
Max

Comment: I think it's a bit too various topic to write a book about. [Wiki](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Electric_power_distribution) can give you some details, the rest is theory

Comment: You will need to talk to them and after convincing them you aren't researching for nefarious reasons, they might share manufacturer and model of equipments they use. And you will need to drive to their substations and look for yourself. Power factor and losses is theory. A university can help you there. People that work with transmission are generally quite passionate about what many consider a dying art.

Comment: @MaxZ, This site intends to be the source for google results, not another google search of links.

Answer (score 3):

Power System Analysis by Bergen is a standard textbook for power systems courses at the senior/graduate student level.

[http://www.amazon.com/Power-Systems-Analysis-2nd-Edition/dp/0136919901](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0136919901)